# Problemas al cargar segunda pagina en adelante de mi DataTables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli, datatables

En mi DataTable tengo como funcionalidad **editar la tabla pulsando click sobre el campo (al estilo de phpmyadmin) y a su vez un botón que realiza una función**.

Cabe decir que mi DataTables tiene la configuración básica para que muestre los **registros de 10 en 10**.

Todos los registros se cargan correctamente (2000 registros), **PERO** tengo un inconveniente al cargar la segunda pagina en adelante de mi DataTables, es decir del registro 11 en adelante (**sólo me permite editar los 10 primeros registros**), debido a que no me permite editar los campos de mi tabla, de manera que solo me deja editar los primeros 10 registros que por predeterminado carga la tabla, haciendo que los demás campos no sean editables y que a su vez no pueda acceder al boton que tengo como dentro de la tabla.

**Agradezco su atención!!!**

Les comparto el codigo.

***Funcion en listarclientes.php que llama a buscarclientes.php

```
        function buscarClientes(){

          $.ajax({
            url:"buscarclientes.php",
            type:"get",
            success: function(data){
              $("#clientes").html(data);
            },
            error: function(){
            }
          })
        }
```

***Archivo buscarclientes.php

*Conexion a base de datos mysqli

```
$sql="SELECT idcliente,nombre,apellido,celular_s from clientes where activo=1";
$stm=$bd->ejecutar($sql);
?>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table id="tablaclientes" class="display" style="width:100%">   
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Contacto</th>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellidos</th>
        <th>Contacto Sec.</th>
        <th>Inhabilitar</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>         
        <?php 
        while($fila=$bd->obtener_fila($stm,0)){
          ?>
          <td data="<?php echo $fila['idcliente'] ?>"><label class="idclientec"><?php echo $fila['idcliente']?></label></td>
          <td data="<?php echo $fila['idcliente'] ?>"><label class="nombrec"><?php echo $fila['nombre']?></label></td>
          <td data="<?php echo $fila['idcliente'] ?>"><label class="apellidoc"><?php echo $fila['apellido']?></label></td>
          <td data="<?php echo $fila['idcliente'] ?>"><label><?php echo $fila['celular_s']?></label></td>
          <td data="<?php echo $fila['idcliente'] ?>" class="inhabilitar" style="cursor:pointer">
            <i class="fa fa-minus" style="color:red"></i></td>
          </tr>
          <?php 
        }
        ?>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Contacto</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Apellidos</th>
          <th>Contacto Sec.</th>
          <th>Inhabilitar</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>

  </div>

  <br>
  <script>

   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tablaclientes').DataTable( {
       "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
     language: {
      "decimal": "",
      "emptyTable": "No hay información",
      "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Entradas",
      "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Entradas",
      "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
      "infoPostFix": "",
      "thousands": ",",
      "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Entradas",
      "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
      "processing": "Procesando...",
      "search": "Buscar:",
      "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
      "paginate": {
        "first": "Primero",
        "last": "Ultimo",
        "next": "Siguiente",
        "previous": "Anterior"
      }
    },
    "pagingType": "full_numbers"
  } );
  } );

</script>


<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".inhabilitar").click(function(){

      var c = confirm('¿Está seguro de Inhabilitar el Cliente con Identificación: '+$(this).attr("data")+'?');

      if(c){
        eliminarCliente($(this).attr("data"))
      }else{
        alert('Ha Pulsado Cancelar')
      }

    })




    $(".idclientec").click(function(){

      $(this).css("display","none")
      var input="<input onblur='ocultaridcliente(this)' type='text' value='"+$(this).text()+"' name='idcliente'> "
      $(this).parent("td").append(input);

    })

    $(".nombrec").click(function(){

      $(this).css("display","none")
      var input="<input onblur='ocultarnombre(this)' type='text' value='"+$(this).text()+"' name='nombre'> "
      $(this).parent("td").append(input);

    })

    $(".apellidoc").click(function(){

      $(this).css("display","none")
      var input="<input onblur='ocultarapellido(this)' type='text' value='"+$(this).text()+"' name='apellido'> "
      $(this).parent("td").append(input);

    })



  })


  /*Funcion Modificar Idcliente*/
  function ocultaridcliente(obj){  
    actualizaridcliente(obj,$(obj).val())
    var label="<label class='idclientec' > "+$(obj).val()+"</label>"
    $(obj).parent("td").html(label)

  }

  function actualizaridcliente(obj,idcliente1){
   var valor=$(obj).parent("td").attr("data");

   datos="idcliente="+valor+"&idcliente1="+idcliente1
   $.ajax({
     url:"../actualizar/actualizaridcliente.php",
     type:"post",
     data: datos,
     success: function(data){
      alert(data)
      buscarClientes()

    },
    error: function(){
      alert(data)

    }

  })


 }




 /*Funcion Modificar Nombre cliente*/
 function ocultarnombre(obj){  
  actualizarclientenombre(obj,$(obj).val())
  var label="<label class='nombrec' > "+$(obj).val()+"</label>"
  $(obj).parent("td").html(label)

}

function actualizarclientenombre(obj,nombre){
 var valor=$(obj).parent("td").attr("data");

 datos="idcliente="+valor+"&nombre="+nombre
 $.ajax({
   url:"../actualizar/actualizarclientenombre.php",
   type:"post",
   data: datos,
   success: function(data){
    alert(data)
    buscarClientes()

  },
  error: function(){
    alert(data)

  }

})


}


/*Funcion Modificar Apellido cliente*/

function ocultarapellido(obj){
  actualizarclienteapellido(obj,$(obj).val())
  var label="<label class='apellidoc' > "+$(obj).val()+"</label>"
  $(obj).parent("td").html(label)

}

function actualizarclienteapellido(obj,apellido){
 var valor=$(obj).parent("td").attr("data");

 datos="idcliente="+valor+"&apellido="+apellido
 $.ajax({
   url:"../actualizar/actualizarclienteapellido.php",
   type:"post",
   data: datos,
   success: function(data){
    alert(data)
    buscarClientes()

  },
  error: function(){
    alert(data)

  }

})


}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Al momento de dibujar tu tabla los primeros 10 registros tienen el evento que delegas con `click` los demas estan ocultos y no se les da ese evento, lo que se puede hacer es darle el evento a la tabla y que parta de ella para buscar los demas elementos, puedes cambiar tus eventos de esta manera

```
$("#tablaclientes").on("click", ".idclientec", function(){})
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte. Me funciona.

Comment: Podrias aceptar la respuesta como correcta para futuras referencias